# Getting Incorrect data for the DateAdd (HOUR, -1, GETDATE())

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have posted a similar question in the url : [DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE()) query is returning old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751896/dateaddhour-1-getdate-query-is-returning-old-data?noredirect=1#comment121529392_68751896)

I am doing a query in which I want the last one hour data. [E:g: `StartTime` is a `DateTime` column of format (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss )

First, since the `StartTime` is in GMT format, I am converting the `StartTime` to a different timezone (EST) at runtime. Please find the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), SWITCHOFFSET(StartTime, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS Runtime,
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), SWITCHOFFSET(EndTime, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS CompletedTime,
    J.[State], J.[Info],
    Robots.UserName,
    Releases.[Name] AS ProcessName,
    Robots.[Name] AS RobotName,
    T.[TenancyName],
    J.[HostMachineName],
    J.TenantId,
FROM 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Jobs] AS J
JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Tenants] AS T ON J.TenantId = T.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Releases] AS Releases ON J.ReleaseId = Releases.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Robots] AS Robots ON J.RobotId = Robots.Id
WHERE
    J.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD (HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND Info LIKE 'Could not start executor.%'
    OR J.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND Info LIKE 'The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.%'
ORDER BY
    Runtime DESC
```

I am facing many problems now with the above query,

1. When I do this, I am able to get the Current date output, but if I execute the query at 8pm, I want the last hour data from 7-8pm , but this returns result from 4pm, 3pm also. (E:g, If I execute at 8/13 12Am , I am getting the result as StartTime: 8/12 20:00 Data.)

The difference between GMT to EST is 4 hours, If the result occurred at 9.30Pm for example and when I execute this query at that time, its not returning the result , but if I execute it at 1:30 am, that is getting returned.

Will difference in Timezone cause the conflict?
Please let me know if need more clear data

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be with your `WHERE` clause.  It appears you intended there to be 2 distinct scenarios, however, in order for the query to return rows both of these conditions must be true

```
 AND Info LIKE 'Could not start executor.%'
 AND Info LIKE 'The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.%'
```

It appears you're missing parentheses in the `WHERE` clause which would distinguish between the two scenario.  Something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), SWITCHOFFSET(StartTime, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS Runtime,
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), SWITCHOFFSET(EndTime, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS CompletedTime,
    J.[State], J.[Info],
    Robots.UserName,
    Releases.[Name] AS ProcessName,
    Robots.[Name] AS RobotName,
    T.[TenancyName],
    J.[HostMachineName],
    J.TenantId,
FROM 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Jobs] AS J
JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Tenants] AS T ON J.TenantId = T.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Releases] AS Releases ON J.ReleaseId = Releases.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    [D716UIPATH].[dbo].[Robots] AS Robots ON J.RobotId = Robots.Id
WHERE
    (J.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD (HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND Info LIKE 'Could not start executor.%')
    OR 
    (J.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND Info LIKE 'The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.%')
ORDER BY
    Runtime DESC;
```

Comment: I resolved the Issue. The problem was with the : WHERE
    (J.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD (HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) in which the (J.StartTime took the Old time zone data and compared it with the GETDATE() WHICH is the Current Timezone). So I used CTE and resolved the issue by comparing GETDATE with the Alias. Thank you!